# Why does first code fragment swap values properly, but second one doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First code fragment:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 7
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a == 7
True
>>> b == 5
True
```

Second code fragment:

```
>>> def swap(first_obj, second_obj):
...     second_obj[:], first_obj[:] = first_obj, second_obj
...
>>> first = [1, 2, 3]
>>> second = [4, 5, 6]
>>> first_content = first[:]
>>> second_content = second[:]
>>> swap(first, second)
>>> print(first, second_content, first == second_content)
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] False
>>> second, first_content, second == first_content)
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] True
```

My task is to write a function that swaps the values of two variables. But it can't return any values. I know that I can add third variable, but I want to find out what's wrong with the second code fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the contents of the list objects directly, not swapping variables. Because the contents of `second_obj` are replaced first, then `second_obj` is used to replace the contents of `first_obj`, you end up with the contents of the `first_obj` list in both lists.

Lets give the list objects reference ids to distinguish them. The variable names `first_obj` and `second_obj` are references themselves, to two lists:

1. `first_obj` references id `{L1}`, value `[1, 2, 3]`
2. `second_obj` references id `{L2}`, value `[4, 5, 6]`

What happens next is this:

- The two lists are pushed on the stack in order, with `{L2}` ending up top.
- The top two entries on the stack are swapped, so now the top of the stack contains first `{L1}` then `{L2}`.
- The top of the stack is assigned to `second_obj[:]`, which replaces all values *in the list `second_obj` references*.  The values contained in `{L1}` are copied over to `{L2}`. `{L2}` now is `[1, 2, 3]`. The top of the stack is removed.
- The top of the stack is assigned to `first_obj[:]`, which replaces all values *in the list `first_obj` references*.  The values contained in `{L2}` are copied over to `{L1}`. `{L1}` now is `[1, 2, 3]`. The top of the stack is removed.

You can make the swap work by creating a copy of `second_obj` first:

```
second_obj[:], first_obj[:] = first_obj, second_obj[:]
```